# Angular 2 does not update FromGroup value automatically

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-template

I am using the recently release 2.0.0 of Angular, basically I have a component which initialize the values of its form template that consists of a input textbox, and a formArray of FormGroup with two input textboxes.

When Initialization is done the binding is working fine, but when I push a new FormGroup to the formArray, the form value does not reflect the new added item until I do some value change in some textbox that was initially binded. Why of this behavior and how can I get the form value updated when some dynamically FormGroup its added?

My component and template code is this:

```js
//initialize the form values
//this_fb is the form builder
setControlsValues(){
  
   this.form_band = this._fb.group({

  name : [ 'test', [ Validators.required ] ],
  bands : this._fb.array([

   this._fb.group({

    name : [ 'band 1', [ Validators.required] ],
    score : 10
   }),
   this._fb.group({

    name : [ 'band 2', [ Validators.required] ],
    score : 8
   })
  ])
   });  
}
  
//push a new FormGroup when user click button
addBand(){
  
  this.form_band.controls.bands.controls.push( 

    this._fb.group({

      name : [ '', Validators.required ],
      score : 0
    })
  );
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="form_band" validate="off">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control"  formControlName="name" autocomplete="off">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group" >
  <h4>Bands</h4>
  <div formArrayName="bands">
   <div *ngFor="let band of form_band.controls.bands.controls; let i=index">
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="score">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn" (click)="addBand()">Add band</button>
 </div>
```

---

**Solved**

I was trying to push the new form group to the controls property of the form array, and it has to be pushed to the form array itself.

I changed the addBand method to this:

```
addBand(){

  this.form_band.controls.bands.push( 

    this._fb.group({

      name : [ '', Validators.required ],
      score : 0
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: Look into `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`. When Ang2 isn't re-rending something it ought to re-render, then my first guess is that there's something it's not watching. You can run `detectChanges()` to force it to check. When I've used this I've also needed to write my own code to check for changes to the property.

Comment: Actually, looking at the new Form page for Ang 2.0 release, I'd guess that there are several things "wrong" with your code, but the fundamental reason why the view isn't re-rendering is because you haven't defined two-way data binding using `[(ngModel)]` syntax. I'm just learning about the changes, so don't take my word for it! Search for the section called "Inside [(ngModel)]". https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

Comment: After learning more about Angular 2 forms I'm coming back to confirm that your UI certainly isn't updating because you implemented the unidirectional data-flow version of forms. This doc explains the two ways to validate forms. The first half explains validating with 2-way data bindings, which is the way for Ang2 to automatically update the UI. The way you're implementing requires that you manually update the UI.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html

Comment: Thanks to all, I already solved it, the issue was that I was trying to push the new form group to the controls property of the form array, and it has to be pushed to the form array itself.

I have edited my question to show what I have changed to make it work.

Comment: @walter Thanks for posting the answer. Had spent lots of hours and now it's fixed.

Comment: Great spot, I was doing exactly the same thing. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the insight, but the ability to be able to push to both form array and form array controls is ambiguous. It took several hours from my life.